# SqlParameter array to object

Tags: c#, arrays

```
SqlParameter[] _parameters = {                
     new SqlParameter( "@IDNumber", Person.IDNumber ),
     new SqlParameter( "@Name", Person.Name ),
     new SqlParameter( "@Surname", Person.Surname )
};
```

How to get the "Name" value from object array without using index? What I want to do is,

```
oPerson.Name = _parameters.Find(@Name).Value;
```

Comment: Considered a `SqlParameterCollection` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
_parameters.Single(p => p.ParameterName == "@Name").Value;
```

This assumes one and only one instance of a `SqlParameter` with a given `ParameterName` exists. If you're unsure if one exists, do the following:

```
var param = _parameters.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ParameterName == "@Name");
if (param != null) { oPerson.Name = param.Value; }
```

Comment: it says system.array does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefault :(

Comment: assuming you're using .NET 3.5, just add `using System.Linq`, otherwise replace with `Array.Find(_parameters, p => p.ParameterName == "@Name").Value`

Comment: I'm using .Net4.0. Now it says, object doesn't contain a definition for ParameterName :(

Comment: my mistake that should have been 'if you're using .NET 3.5+', so 4.0 qualifies; just add `using System.Linq;` to your using directives. If you followed that already - are you certain `_parameters` is `SqlParameter[]` not `object[]`? You can always try `_parameters.OfType<SqlParameter>().Single(p => p.ParameterName == "@Name").Value;`

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq, it is easy

```
string pName = "@Name";
var p = _parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParameterName == pName);
if(p != null) 
    oPerson.Name = p.Value.ToString();
```

I assume that you need this code because you are unsure about the presence or not of your parameter. So using `FirstOrDefault` allows to test for the result without using directly the Value property if your parameter doesn't exists in the collection

Comment: it says system.array does not contain a definition for firstordefault :(

Comment: Do you think I can extract one SqlParameter object from whole array? just by giving the parameters name?

Comment: That's what the code above does. var p it is a SqlParameter. To use the example you need Linq of course. What Framework version are you using?

Comment: That's strange, the accepted answer uses the same property :-)

Comment: I was doing something wrong at that moment. Your answer is correct too. Too bad I can't mark two answers as accepted answer at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `First` method and get the parameter by it's `Name`.

```
oPerson.Name = _parameters.First(x => x.ParameterName == "@Name").Value;
```

Comment: @BonusKun you should include the `System.Linq` namespace with: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Note that this works because arrays of type `T[]` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, upon which the Linq extension methods are defined.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq like in

```
oPerson.Name = _parameters.First( param => param.ParameterName.Equals("@Name")).Value;
```

to search for the value of `"@Name"` again.